# How to show items into shopping cart when click add to cart button in laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

[image]I am trying to show items into shopping cart when i click add to card button but i am facing some errors How to fit it error

Please see error 
Non-static method Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() should not be called statically

https://flareapp.io/share/Bm06697x

**Controller**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart;

   class CartController extends Controller
   {
   public function cart()
   { 
   return view('front_end/cart');
   }

    public function addcart(Request $request){
    $image = [$request->product_image];

    $add=Cart::add(
        $request->productid,
       $request->product_name,
       $request->qty,
       $request->product_price,
      $image

     );
    return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');
     }
    }
```

**html view**

```
              <tbody class="cart-table__body">

              @foreach(Cart::content()  as $items)
              <tr class="cart-table__row">
              <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--image">
              <a href=""><img src="{{$items->product_image}}" alt=""></a>
              </td>
              <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--product">
              <a href="" class="cart-table__product-name">{{$items->product_name}}</a>        
              </td>
             <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--price" data-title="Price">{{$items- 
              >product_price}}</td>

             <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--quantity" data-title="Quantity">
             <div class="input-number">
             <input class="form-control input-number__input" type="number" min="1" value="{{$items->qty}}">
             <div class="input-number__add"></div>
             <div class="input-number__sub"></div>
             </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--total" data-title="Total"></td>      
              <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--remove">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-light btn-sm btn-svg-icon">
              <svg width="12px" height="12px">
              <use xlink:href="{{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#cross-12')}}"></use>
              </svg>
             </a>
            </td>
            </tr>
             @endforeach     
             </tbody>
```

Comment: Cart::content() you should not use this in blade. make a function and return a collection or array and use that in blade that would prevent the above error

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your controller and pass data your  in view

```
        $cart_list = Cart::content();
        $cart_data = [];
        foreach($cart_list as $cart){
               $cart_data [] = [
                  //define keys as per your cart's content and pass $cart_data in your view
               ];
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Sorry i was reading the question wrong. 
Where is defined your function add() just add static

```
public static function add() {
//.....
}
```

or

```
static public function add() {
    // ......
}
```

**OLD POST**
I don't see, where u're defining which cart is for which user, but I would do it in this way.

**Controller**

```
$userId = Auth::id(); // Get the ID from Session of a logged user.

$carts = Cart::where('user_id', $userId)->get(); // Get all products linked to user

return view('cart')->withCarts($carts); // Return the view with data
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($carts as $cart) // U foreach every product linked to user

{{ $cart->product_name }}
{{ $cart->product_price}}
{{ $cart->product_image }}

@endforeach
```

If the user is not logged in, you can create a cart with the cookie id on youtube are hundreds of tutorials how to make an e-commerce cart.

Hope this helps

Comment: i have used static keyword but  i have same error Non-static method Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() should not be called statically                                             https://flareapp.io/share/w5BGAXm8#F43

Comment: And if u try to change `use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart;` to `use Cart;`